# Print Dialog Box in Win32

Tags: c++, winapi

I came across this tutorial  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BECw2Ouz4I0

I went ahead and added  print dialog box based on that example in my code. I end up having three 3error:

PRINTDLG is undefined
PD_RETURNDC is undefined 
PrintDlg is undefined

How do I defined these?

```
  LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
 {
int wmId, wmEvent;
PAINTSTRUCT ps;

HDC hdc;

switch (message)
{
case WM_COMMAND:
    wmId    = LOWORD(wParam);
    wmEvent = HIWORD(wParam);
    // Parse the menu selections:
    switch (wmId)
    {

    case IDM_ABOUT:
        DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, About);
        break;
    case IDM_EXIT:
        DestroyWindow(hWnd);
        break;

    case IDM_PRINT:
        DestroyWindow(hWnd);            
   {
static PRINGDLG pDlg;
static DOCINFO dInfo;

dInfo.cbSize = sizeof (dInfo);
dInfo.lpszDocName = L"Printing!"; 

pDlg.Flags =  PD_RETURNDC;
pDlg.hInstance = (HINSTANCE) GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_HINSTANCE);
pDlg.IStructSize = sizeof(pDlg);
pDlg.hwndOwner - hWnd;

PrintDlg(&pDlg);

StartDoc(pDlg.hdc,&dInfo);

StartPage(pDlg.hdc);

TextOut(pDlg.hDC,0,0,L"Hello",6);

EndPage(pDlg.hdc);

EndDoc(pDlg.hdc);

ReleaseDC(hWnd, pDlg.hdc);

   }
```

Would I defined them in the cpp file, rc, or h file?

Thanks

```
   // Win32Lesson1.cpp : Defines the entry point for the application.
   //

  #include "stdafx.h"
  #include "Win32Lesson1.h"
  #include <windows.h>
  #include "Resource.h"

  #define MAX_LOADSTRING 100


  bool gbDrawLine1     = false;
  bool gbDrawEllipse1  = false;
  bool gbDrawRectangle1 = false; 
 bool gbDrawLine2 = false; 
 bool gbDrawRectangle2 = false; 
 bool gbDrawEllipse2  = false;






      // Global Variables:
    HINSTANCE hInst;        // current instance
   TCHAR szTitle[MAX_LOADSTRING];                   // The title bar text
   TCHAR szWindowClass[MAX_LOADSTRING];         // the main window class name

   // Forward declarations of functions included in this code module:
  ATOM              MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance);
  BOOL              InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int);
 LRESULT CALLBACK   WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
  INT_PTR CALLBACK  About(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

  int APIENTRY _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                 HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                 LPTSTR    lpCmdLine,
                 int       nCmdShow)
 {
UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

// TODO: Place code here.
MSG msg;
HACCEL hAccelTable;

// Initialize global strings
LoadString(hInstance, IDS_APP_TITLE, szTitle, MAX_LOADSTRING);
LoadString(hInstance, IDC_WIN32LESSON1, szWindowClass, MAX_LOADSTRING);
MyRegisterClass(hInstance);

// Perform application initialization:
if (!InitInstance (hInstance, nCmdShow))
{
    return FALSE;
}

hAccelTable = LoadAccelerators(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_WIN32LESSON1));

// Main message loop:
while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
{
    if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
}

return (int) msg.wParam;
   }



 //
 //  FUNCTION: MyRegisterClass()
 //
//  PURPOSE: Registers the window class.
//
//  COMMENTS:
//
  //    This function and its usage are only necessary if you want this code
 //    to be compatible with Win32 systems prior to the 'RegisterClassEx'
//    function that was added to Windows 95. It is important to call this function
 //    so that the application will get 'well formed' small icons associated
 //    with it.
 //
 ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
WNDCLASSEX wcex;

wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

wcex.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
wcex.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0;
wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;
wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
wcex.hIcon          = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_WIN32LESSON1));
wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
wcex.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
wcex.lpszMenuName   = MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_WIN32LESSON1);
wcex.lpszClassName  = szWindowClass;
wcex.hIconSm        = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SMALL));

return RegisterClassEx(&wcex);
}

  //
 //   FUNCTION: InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int)
 //
    //   PURPOSE: Saves instance handle and creates main window
 //
   //   COMMENTS:
  //
   //        In this function, we save the instance handle in a global variable and
  //        create and display the main program window.
   //



   BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
  {
  HWND hWnd;


  hInst = hInstance; // Store instance handle in our global variable

  hWnd = CreateWindow(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
  CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

  if (!hWnd)
  {
   return FALSE;
  }

  ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
  UpdateWindow(hWnd);

 return TRUE;
 }


   //
   //  FUNCTION: WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)
     //
   //  PURPOSE:  Processes messages for the main window.
  //
  //  WM_COMMAND    - process the application menu
  //  WM_PAINT  - Paint the main window
  //  WM_DESTROY    - post a quit message and return
```

Comment: I don't think you want to `DestroyWindow` when you get `IDM_PRINT`.

Comment: Plus, try [searching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646843(v=vs.85).aspx), then look at the required header includes.

Comment: I am still learning C++... What would I replace DestroyWindow with in the IDM_PRINT.

Comment: Do you really want to destroy your window when you print? I would think now. And if not, you don't need to do anything other than your printing code. Which, by the way, would be cleaner to put into its own function.

Comment: Oh I am understanding a bit more now. The destroywindow works for exiting the program but not printing. Would I add a dialogbox code in its place?

Comment: I still am unsure how to fix the errors of them being undefined.

Comment: Where in the code you posted did you `#include <windows.h>`?

Comment: At the being of the cpp file

Comment: // Win32Lesson1.cpp : Defines the entry point for the application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Win32Lesson1.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include "Resource.h"

Comment: Please start from the basics.  Only include `windows.h` and then introduce those other headers later.  The PRINTDLG is defined in windows.h as specified here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646843%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @user3677801 - Also, get rid of stdafx.h.  It is not needed in a tutorial on Windows programming.  If you're using Visual Studio, make sure you turn off the precompiled header generation also from the project settings.  Until you know what you're doing with respect to headers, stay away from `stdafx.h` and/or precompiled headers.

Comment: Ok- I will try to work on this later today. Thanks for the information about the headers

Comment: So I took away all the headers except the windows.h- 2 of the errors went away except the PRINTDLG is undefined still